# How to keep WinForms designer from generating Click handlers?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a big legacy WinForms app, and there's a form with a toolbar and all the buttons in the designer have names like `ts*` and code in the code behind designer file like this:

```
        this.tsPlanner.Name = "tsPlanner";
        this.tsPlanner.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 38);
        this.tsPlanner.Text = "Planner";
        this.tsPlanner.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tsPlanner_Click);
```

I'm trying to clean up this code so that instead of each button having its own Click event, there's a central dispatcher that handles all the buttons.

So I delete the Click handlers and the event hookup for them, but every time the designer file is regenerated, it adds back this line, and since the handler event is now removed, this causes compilation errors.

I can't find anywhere in the designer that tells Visual Studio that I want automatic event hookup. How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Is it still listed in the properties of the control? even though you removed it in the code? is it regenerating it because it hasnt refreshed properly through out vs?

Comment: How did you delete the event hookup?  Editing *.Designer.cs while you have Visual Studio open is a dicey proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Designer code is just c# partial class. Open Form.Designer.cs, delete event subscription, delete event handler funcion. Save all. Recompile all. Close all windows. Try to reopen designer.
It seems that you open in designer one form and edit code for another one.

Comment: It does seem that the code behind file gets confused if you have the code and designer view open at the same time. Closing everything seems to have fixed this. Thanks.